# Handler for UsernameNotFoundException & BadCredentialsException in spring oauth

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to setup a handler for UsernameNotFoundException & BadCredentialsException for Password Grant oauth flow (Spring-Outh). The purpose for the handler, is whenever any one of those exceptions are thrown increment a counter in the DB.

I am not sure at what point this handler needs to setup.

```
 <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"   authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="ROLE_USER"  />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"  />

    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />

    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>


<!-- The OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block so we can deal with authorization and error handling 
    separately. This isn't mandatory, but it makes it easier to control the behaviour. -->
<http pattern="/public/**" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/public/registration" access="ROLE_USER,SCOPE_READ"  />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<http use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/public/registration/activation/**" access="permitAll" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="daoProvider">
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>


<beans:bean id="customUserDetailService" class="com.cointraders.api.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />


<beans:bean id="daoProvider" class="com.cointraders.api.daoauthproviders.CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailService"/>
    <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="clientDetails" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.JdbcClientDetailsService">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>   

<oauth:authorization-server  client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials/>
    <oauth:custom-grant token-granter-ref="randomTokenGrant" />
</oauth:authorization-server>
```

Comment: Take a look at `@ExceptionHandler` annotation

Comment: The `@ExceptionHandler` won't work as the error is thrown from a filter and not from within the `DispatcherServlet`. Implement a `AuthenticationFailureHandler` and register that with the filter. Or subclass the filter and override the `unsuccessfulAuthentication`.

Comment: Actually those exceptions should not be thrown from a filter if they relate to password grants. The best way to trap them would be to provide your own `AuthenticationManager` to the token granter.

Comment: @DaveSyer any examples of how to extend the authenticationManager (extend what class)? Also, how to hook it up in the beans configuration? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`AuthenticationManager` is a very simple interface. I don't think anyone needs help implementing that. And the authorization server configuration DSLs have explicit spots where you plugin an `AuthenticationManager` (e.g. The `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` in Java, like here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/annotation/jdbc/src/main/java/demo/Application.java).

Comment: Thanks @Dave Syer for the reply. What's the default implementation for the authenticationManager? Want to see the source to ensure I'm following the correct design pattern and logic. Also, I had a look at the authorization-server DSL and not seeing any attributes that speaks to the authenticationManager.

Comment: Also, I adjusted my question above to include my bean snippet.

Comment: You haven't even enabled password grants in the `<authorization-server/>`. If you do that you will find you can set an authentication manager in the granter.

Comment: Yes I know, the randomTokenGrant custom grant type works the same way as Password Grant (extends it and just added a few custom code). The reason why I mentioned Password grant type was for simplicity.

Comment: OK, so it's all in your control in your custom granter. What's the problem?

Comment: As I mentioned before. I wanted an area to catch  UsernameNotFoundException & BadCredentialsException errors; just so that I can log values in my DB when those errors happens. You mentioned earlier that I ought to use authenticationManager but, I wanted to see the source for the default implementation for the authenticationManager. Also if I do come up with a custom authentication manager, how would I be able to integrate it with authorization-server? seeing that attributes specified by the DSL does not allow straight integration with the autheenticationManager.